# TLS security warnings from api.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, https

Each time an API request is made over HTTPS, Firefox generates the following message in the error console:

[image]

Curious, I looked up [RFC 5746](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746) and the document covers the following:

> #### Transport Layer Security (TLS) Renegotiation Indication Extension
>
> Secure Socket Layer (SSL) and Transport Layer Security (TLS) renegotiation are vulnerable to an attack in which the attacker forms a TLS connection with the target server, injects content of his choice, and then splices in a new TLS connection from a client. The server treats the client's initial TLS handshake as a renegotiation and thus believes that the initial data transmitted by the attacker is from the same entity as the subsequent client data.  **This specification defines a TLS extension to cryptographically tie renegotiations to the TLS connections they are being performed over, thus preventing this attack.**
>
> *(Emphasis mine.)*

I realize that this probably isn't a terribly serious problem, but it does appear to be a bit of a security concern. Is there any chance this could be fixed?

---

**Edit:** not sure if it's related, but it gets worse:

[image]

I get this dialog box in Firefox 9.1 if I attempt to authenticate an app using the implicit flow.

Comment: Have you tried not on Windows 8?

Comment: Nope. But I can ask someone on Ubuntu to try it later on and see if they get the warning.

Comment: We don't use akamai ... do you have a proxy server on your end that could be using their services?

Comment: @Zypher: Do you use Quantserve?

Comment: Nope, well, we have the quantcast stuff on the main sites but i double kevin put it in the api ...

Comment: @Zypher: The API does have auth pages... that's where I'm getting the error - could that be it?

Comment: have to let @kevinmontrose weigh in

Comment: I can't reproduce the dialog, and we don't have any links to Quantcast on the implicit dialog.  Looking into the RFC 5746 stuff, doesn't look like an easy fix.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: Perhaps it's [this page](https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success) since my extension uses that.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison - ah, that's more believable.  Still can't get firefox to freak out with a dialog, but there is a dodge reference to quantcast there.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: Yeah, the dialog only shows up every once and a while. This might help: try visiting [this](https://edge.quantserve.com/) link and see if the warning displays. It seems like a problem with `edge.quantserve.com` getting accessed over HTTPS.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison give it a go again, offending content should be excised from that page.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: Seems to be working now. I haven't seen the warning anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is both [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), really.

The offending material was excised a while ago, so that warning shouldn't be displayed ever.

The RFC 5746 message will go away when we next do an upgrade on our SSL load balancer... which is planned, but not going to happen over night either.